# Indentation error, unexpected indentation

Tags: python, indentation

I've read all the previous instances of this question and tried many different things to fix it. I have made sure the spaces are not tabs using notepad++, and I've tried to check for syntax errors, but can't find anything. What am I doing wrong. 
I'm trying to run this code from a GitHub repository, though i'm quite new to it all. There are quite a few errors, but i'm trying to work through them as I come to them.
The one that's got me stuck is the following:

```
if(x_dimension_variable==y_dimension_variable):   File "<stdin>", line 1
     if(x_dimension_variable==y_dimension_variable):
    ^ IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

Here is the code

```
import cv2 as cv

import numpy as np

image_variable=cv.imread(r"C:\Users\Joe_C\Documents\Coding\Git\Imagerecognition\digits.png")

image_grey=cv.cvtColor(image_variable,cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

image_cells=[np.hsplit(row,100) for row in np.split(image_grey,50)]

array_variable=np.array(image_cells)

print("The shape of our cell Array"+str(array_variable.shape))

data_train=array_variable[:,:70].reshape(-1,400).astype(np.float32)

data_test=array_variable[:,70:100].reshape(-1,400).astype(np.float32)

dataset_variable=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

data_train_label=np.repeat(dataset_variable,350)[:,np.newaxis]

data_test_label=np.repeat(dataset_variable,150)[:,np.newaxis]

knn=cv.ml.KNearest_create()

knn.train(data_train,cv.ml.ROW_SAMPLE,data_train_label)

return_variable,result_variable,neighbours_variable,distance_variable=knn.findNearest(data_test,k=3)

matches_variable=result_variable==data_test_label
correct_matches_variable=np.count_nonzero(matches_variable)
accuracy_correct_matches_variable=correct_matches_variable*(100.0/result_variable.size)
print("Accuracy is %.2f"% + accuracy_correct_matches_variable + "%")

def array_contour(data_contour):
    if cv.contourArea(data_contour)>10:
        moments_variable = cv.moments(data_contour)
        return int(moments_variable['m10']/moments_variable['m00'])
    else:
        return int(0)

def square_check(not_square):
    set_variable=[0,0,0]
    image_dimension=not_square.shape
    x_dimension_variable=image_dimension[0]
    y_dimension_variable=image_dimension[1]

    if(x_dimension_variable==y_dimension_variable):
        square_variable=not_square
        return square_variable
    else:
        double_size_variable=cv.resize(not_square,(2*y_dimension_variable,2*x_dimension_variable),interpolation=cv.INTER_CUBIC)
        x_dimension_variable=x_dimension_variable*2
        y_dimension_variable=y_dimension_variable*2

        if(x_dimension_variable>y_dimension_variable):
            pad_variable=int((x_dimension_variable-y_dimension_variable)/2)
            double_size_square_variable=cv.copyMakeBorder(double_size_variable,0,0,pad_variable,pad_variable,cv.BORDER_CONSTANT,value=set_variable)
            cv.copyMakeBorder(double_size_square_variable,0,0,0,0,0)
        else:
            pad_variable=int((y_dimension_variable-x_dimension_variable)/2)
            double_size_square_variable=cv.copyMakeBorder(double_size_variable,0,0,pad_variable,pad_variable,cv.BORDER_CONSTANT,value=set_variable)

    return double_size_square_variable

def resize_pixel(dimensions_image,image_parameter):
    buffer_pixels_variable=4
    dimensions_image=dimensions_image-buffer_pixels_variable
    squared_image=image_parameter
    r_float_variable=float(dimensions_image)/squared_image.shape[1]
    dimension_dim=(dimensions_image,int(squared_image.shape[0]*r_float_variable))
    resized_image=cv.resize(image_parameter,dimension_dim,interpolation=cv.INTER_AREA)
    image_dimension_r=resized_image.shape
    x_dimension_r=image_dimension_r[0]
    y_dimension_r=image_dimension_r[1]
    set_variable_r=[0,0,0]
    if(x_dimension_r>y_dimension_r):
        resized_image=cv.copyMakeBorder(resized_image,0,0,0,1,cv.BORDER_CONSTANT,value=set_variable_r)
    if(x_dimension_r<y_dimension_r):
        resized_image=cv.copyMakeBorder(resized_image,1,0,0,0,cv.BORDER_CONSTANT,value=set_variable_r)
        resized_image_r=cv.copyMakeBorder(resized_image,2,2,2,2,cv.BORDER_CONSTANT,value=set_variable_r)
        image_dimension_2_r=resized_image_r.shape
    x_image_dimension_r=image_dimension_2_r[0]
    y_image_dimension_r=image_dimension_2_r[1]
    return resized_image_r

image_variable_2=cv.imread(r"C:\Users\Joe_C\Documents\Coding\Git\Imagerecognition\num.png")
image_grey_2=cv.cvtColor(image_variable_2,cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv.imshow("Image 2",image_variable_2)
cv.imshow("Grey 2", image_grey_2)
cv.waitKey(0)

image_blurred=cv.GaussianBlur(image_grey_2,(5,5),0)
cv.imshow("Blurred Image", image_blurred)
cv.waitKey(0)

image_edged=cv.Canny(image_blurred,0,80)
cv.imshow("Canny Edged", image_edged)#
cv.waitKey(0)

_, contours_image, _=cv.findContours(image_edged.copy(),cv.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours_image=sorted(contours_image, key=array_contour, reverse=False)

full_number=[]

for c in contours_image:
    (x,y,w,h)=cv.boundingRect(c)

    cv.drawContours(image_variable_2, contours_image,-1,(0,255,0),1)
    cv.imshow("Countours",image_variable_2)

    if w >= 5 and h >= 25:

        roi = image_blurred[y:y + h, x:x +w]

        ret, roi = cv.threshold(roi,127,255,cv.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
        squared = square_check(roi)
        final = resize_pixel(20, squared)
        cv.imshow("Final Image",final)
        final_array = final.reshape((1,400))
        final_array = final_array.astype(np.float32)
        ret, result, neighbors, dist=knn.findNearest(final_array, k=1)
        number = str(int(float(result[0])))
        full_number.append(number)
        cv.rectangle(image_variable_2,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,0,255),2)
        cv.putText(image_variable_2,number,(x,y+155),cv.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX,2,(255,0,0),2)
        cv.imshow("Image2",image_variable_2)
        cv.waitKey(0)

cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Are you typing this into an interactive interpreter session by hand? That error messages looks like you are. You're supposed to put this in a file and run that.

Comment: btw your ifs don’t need the round brackets.

Comment: you could just [download](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Xacrolyte/Number-Recognition/master/Basic_Init1.py) the file as .py and edit it afterwards, instead of typing it into the REPL. however, I strongly advise working on easier code before you tackle a 185 line machine learning program.

Comment: Cannot reproduce.

Comment: Thanks for all your responses and patience. I know I have a lot to learn.
I am editing the code in Notepad++ and then copy/paste into Python app. 
I tried easier programs with success using this method.
Running the .py file (as downloaded from github) gives same output as running code in Python 3.8 64bit app (on WIndows 10). Pops up same windows, but then app window closes, program doesn't complete all steps, but you can't see what errors occur.